# How to restrict other active directory user in multi tenant application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, angular2-directives

I have enabled multi tenant access to my app in azure portal and now i'm able to access my app from other active directory users.I mean multi tenant access is working.
I enabled multi tenant access to my app like as shown in image:

[image]

But now i need to restrict some user from other tenants.
I tried so many articles but i didn't get correct result

I followed this article but here i didn't get how to add users to the Tenant restrictions
[in this url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-tenant-restrictions)

Any answer appreciated

**Thanks in Advance......!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AAD Enables you, as an Administrator of a Tenant, to control which applications users in your tenant are able to access.

However, it does not enable you, as a Multi-Tenant App Developer, to control what kinds of tenants or users can authenticate to your app. Instead, you must build that logic into your application, using details from the Graph API to learn about the logged in user, which tenant they are from, what groups they are a part of, etc...

[Microsoft Graph Overview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview)

Comment: In-addition, it's responsibility of the admin of other tenants who should decide grant which permission to their organization because he/she is more familiar with their tenants. This is one of advantage of claims based application.

Comment: Hi Shawan,To restrict other active directory user in multi tenant application we need to implement logic in our code right.